# Guidance on when to chose virtual machines or physical machines over containers

Tags: docker, containers, virtual-machine, devops, vmware

There are many articles and videos comparing containers, virtual machines, physical machines. However almost all information is theoretical: containers are fast, VMs are secure, etc. But I could not find description of specific use cases or guidance on when to choose virtual machines, physical machines, but not containers. So, currently I cannot imagine situation when somebody gives recommendation to not use containers.

Question:

- Could you please list specific applications or solutions when you would recommend using VMs, but not container?
- Could you please list specific applications or solutions when you would recommend using OS over bare metal, but not containers or VMs?

Here is example of answer I would appreciate to get (note, that I am not sure if this information is correct):

---

Use case 1: Edge Router

Edge router is a router which connects organizational network to the Internet. Also, in this case it is assumed, that vendor of the router provides it not as device but as a software package (virtualized router).

Edge router most probably will be one of target of hacker's attacks. Thus security requirements come to the first place.

Containers are not recommended in this case. By default containers provide mediocre level of security. Strong security can be achieved with complex configuration (what configuration?) but this is more difficult than in case of VM or bare metal. In addition, high security level may require special [hardened Linux kernel](https://docs.windriver.com/bundle/Wind_River_Linux_Carrier_Grade_Profile_Users_Guide_9_1/page/rnb1487717713115.html), however containers technology does not allow adjusting kernel configuration.

Virtual Machines would be a good choice if vendor of the router provides software as VM image or when organization has many edge routers (for example, many offices with internet access points), and has (or is ready to create) well-established process of preparation of VM images. In this case using VMs will simplify rollout, update and healing the virtualized edge router. VM also provides high security level; nevertheless is it still recommended to place such a VM in a separate server and to not share same server with other applications/VMs to avoid cross-VM attacks.

Physical machine would be a good choice if router vendor provides router's software as an application package (not as a VM) such as .rpm, and rollout, update and healing processes are not expected to take much efforts; this might be the case when  when company has few routers (so updates can be performed manually or automated with tools like Ansible), and couple of hour of planned and unplanned downtime is acceptable.

Use case 2: ...

---

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague so I'll try my best:

you'd usually allocate work to containers when you have a few separate applications with limited physical resources and you'd like to run them each with their own different environment (different runtime version, architecture and dependencies) which managing on a machine (physical or virtual) would be cumbersome.

you'd use a VM when you want specifically a feature that containers couldn't satisfy or it would just be a headache to set them up with it and a simple quick and easy VM could solve (and again you have limited resources you'd like to share between use cases)

and finally, a physical machine when performance is of the essence like I/O requests and latency around that.

you can also mix and match to match each tier needs:

we need to run many applications that VM would be too much of an overhead for them and containers would make their handling more automated and streamline so containers with k8s, but on the other hand, we want local storage offered to those containers to be very fast so we run the k8s cluster on physical machines.

if recoverability would be of the essence we would have used VM due to the options of snapshotting VM states over time.

It's all a big LEGO set you can mix and match depending on your use case and needs

Comment: Thank you for the response. Could you provide some examples of solutions that employ "features that containers couldn't satisfy" and for which "performance is of the essence" so that you would not put them into containers?

Comment: Containers when you want many different environment on the same hardware or if you'd like to consistently preform and action that requires a very specific setting that also could be changed in a heartbeat just as fast. And with physical machines when latency between hardware components can't be heandered by virtualization layers or other form of isolation

Comment: "And with physical machines when latency between hardware components can't be heandered by virtualization layers or other form of isolation" - could you provide some examples when this is the case?

Comment: If you need very fast disk access like when using db or with data science working very big datasets you might prefer using physical machines to reduce any latency the hypervisor or other virtualization layers might create

Comment: @AlexShykov if this answer helped you please accept it